# custom paging in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with laravel:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/711eH.png)
I want to show `1,2,3...191,192`. When current page in the middle, I want to show: `1,2..., 5,6, 7...191,192`

Comment: You can create your own custom paggination view. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: I've been tried, but $elements variable is array which is information about url, I do not know how to control it